# Is it acceptable to measure time elapsed by iteratively blocking a thread for a fixed period and then multiply said period by the loop count?

Tags: c, algorithm, time, concurrency, real-time

I work for a company that produces automatic machines, and I help maintain their software that controls the machines. The software runs on a real-time operating system, and consists of multiple threads running concurrently. The code bases are legacy, and have substantial technical debts. Among all the issues that the code bases exhibit, one stands out as being rather bizarre to me; most of the timing algorithms that involve the computation of time elapsed to realize common timed features such as timeouts, delays, recording time spent in a particular state, and etc., basically take the following form:

```
unsigned int shouldContinue = 1;
unsigned int blockDuration = 1;    // Let's say 1 millisecond.
unsigned int loopCount = 0;
unsigned int elapsedTime = 0;

while (shouldContinue)
{
    .
    . // a bunch of statements, selections and function calls
    .
    
    blockingSystemCall(blockDuration);
    
    .
    . // a bunch of statements, selections and function calls
    .
    
    loopCount++;
    elapsedTime = loopCount * blockDuration;
}
```

The `blockingSystemCall` function can be any operating system's API that suspends the current thread for the specified `blockDuration`. The `elapsedTime` variable is subsequently computed by basically multiplying `loopCount` by `blockDuration` or by any equivalent algorithm.

To me, this kind of timing algorithm is wrong, and is not acceptable under most circumstances. All the instructions in the loop, including the condition of the loop, are executed sequentially, and each instruction requires measurable CPU time to execute. Therefore, the actual time elapsed is strictly greater than the value of `elapsedTime` in any given instance after the loop starts. Consequently, suppose the CPU time required to execute all the statements in the loop, denoted by *d*, is constant. Then, `elapsedTime` lags behind the actual time elapsed by `loopCount` • *d* for any `loopCount` > 0; that is, the deviation grows according to an arithmetic progression. This sets the lower bound of the deviation because, in reality, there will be additional delays caused by thread scheduling and time slicing, depending on other factors.

In fact, not too long ago, while testing a new data-driven predictive maintenance feature which relies on the operation time of a machine, we discovered that the operation time reported by the software lagged behind that of a standard reference clock by a whopping three hours after the machine was in continuous operation for just over two days. It was through this test that I discovered the algorithm outlined above, which I swiftly determined to be the root cause.

Coming from a background where I used to implement timing algorithms on bare-metal systems using timer interrupts, which allows the CPU to carry on with the execution of the business logic while the timer process runs in parallel, it was shocking for me to have discovered that the algorithm outlined in the introduction is used in the industry to compute elapsed time, even more so when a typical operating system already encapsulates the timer functions in the form of various easy-to-use public APIs, liberating the programmer from the hassle of configuring a timer via hardware registers, raising events via interrupt service routines, etc.

The kind of timing algorithm as illustrated in the skeleton code above is found in at least two code bases independently developed by two distinct software engineering teams from two subsidiary companies located in two different cities, albeit within the same state. This makes me wonder whether it is how things are normally done in the industry or it is just an isolated case and is not widespread.

So, the question is, is the algorithm shown above common or acceptable in calculating elapsed time, given that the underlying operating system already provides highly optimized time-management system calls that can be used right out of the box to accurately measure elapsed time or even used as basic building blocks for creating higher-level timing facilities that provide more intuitive methods similar to, e.g., the [Timer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) in C#?

Comment: It kind of depends on what OS you are running on. A RTOS will guarantee how context switches are done, a desktop OS won't.

Comment: @SupportUkraine In other words, such an algorithm should only be used as a last resort. As for whether it was independently developed, one of the two subsidiary companies was co-founded by a chief software engineer who had worked for that other company for many years prior.  So you were right, it was not entirely independent...

Comment: *we discovered that the operation time reported by the software lagged behind that of a standard reference clock by a whopping three hours after the machine was in continuous operation for just over two days*  You didn't know this in advance?  If you didn't know this, why is it a problem? "It's been doing this for X **years**, we didn't know it, but now we have to rewrite everything to make it better!"  Really?!?  I'll agree with @SupportUkraine here - you're going to spend a lot of effort, with significant risk, to make huge changes that change ... nothing.

Comment: Recommendation: This question is somewhat verbose. It's easier for us to read, parse, and provide an answer efficiently if you only include necessary details. e.g., give us the code, tell us that it's on an RTOS, define `blockingSystemCall`, and pose the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that calculating elapsed time that way is inaccurate -- since it assumes that the blocking call will take exactly the amount of time indicated, and that everything that happens outside of the blocking system call will take no time at all, which would only be true on an infinitely-fast machine.    Since actual machines are not infinitely fast, the elapsed-time calculated this way will always be somewhat less than the actual elapsed time.

As to whether that's acceptable, it's going to depend on how much timing accuracy your program needs.  If it's just doing a rough estimate to make sure a function doesn't run for "too long", this might be okay.  OTOH if it is trying for accuracy (and in particular accuracy over a long period of time), then this approach won't provide that.

FWIW the more common (and more accurate) way to measure elapsed time would be something like this:

```
const unsigned int startTime = current_clock_time();
while (shouldContinue)
{
   loopCount++;
   elapsedTime = current_clock_time() - startTime;
}
```

This has the advantage of not "drifting away" from the accurate value over time, but it does assume that you have a `current_clock_time()` type of function available, and that it's acceptable to call it within the loop.  (If `current_clock_time()` is very expensive, or doesn't provide some real-time performance guarantees that the calling routine requires, that might be a reason not to do it this way)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is it not true that, in situations in which hardware timers are readily accessible or the underlying operating system already provide a set of system calls that simulate timer interrupts, one should learn to use them, instead of rolling their own algorithm that uses CPU time to do the counting, regardless of the required timing accuracy?

Comment: By the way, I believe the algorithm that make use of `current_clock_time()` above does not drift away only if the system time itself is periodically synchronized with a reference clock. For example, in [RMOS3](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/31646454/rmos3-v3-50-released-for-delivery?dti=0&lc=en-CY), the system time is expected to have deviations of about 9 seconds per week even when HPET is enabled.

Comment: I don’t think timer interrupts are necessary for this use case, although they can be useful for other things.

Comment: If you’re concerned with current_clock_time() drifting away from something, you have to define what that something is… presumably some other (external?) clock.  If that’s a problem, then sure, you’ll need to synchronize the local clock to the external clock.  OTOH if you only need your behavior to depend on the local clock, and it doesn’t need to track with the external clock, then there’s no need to sync the local clock to the external clock.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these loops do what you think they do.

In a RTOS, the purpose of a loop like this is usually to perform a task at regular intervals.

`blockingSystemCall(N)` probably does not just sleep for N milliseconds like you think it does.  It probably sleeps until N milliseconds after the last time your thread woke up.

More accurately, *all* the sleeps your thread has performed since starting are added to the thread start time to get the time at which the OS will try to wake the thread up.  If your thread woke up due to an I/O event, then the last one of those times could be used instead of the thread start time. The point is that the inaccuracies in all these start times are *corrected*, so your thread wakes up at regular intervals and the elapsed time measurement is *perfectly accurate* according to the RTOS master clock.

There could also be very good reasons for measuring elapsed time by the RTOS master clock instead of a more accurate wall clock time, in addition to simplicity.  This is because all of the guarantees that an RTOS provides (which is the reason you are using a RTOS in the first place) are provided in that time scale.  The amount of time taken by one task can affect the amount of time you are guaranteed to have available for other tasks, *as measured by this clock*.

It may or may not be a problem that your RTOS master clock runs slow by 3 hours every 2 days...